# Consulta SQL por tipo de dato

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
     SELECT 

       COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTALDIA, se.SEXO
FROM 
       CONDUCTORES co
       JOIN TRAMITE tr ON co.conductor_id=tr.conductor_id
       join LICENCIAS lic on tr.licencia_id=lic.licencia_id
       join CAT_SEXO se on se.SEXO_ID=co.sexo_id      
WHERE   

       YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE())
       AND MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())

        GROUP BY se.SEXO ORDER BY TOTALDIA ASC, SEXO asc
```

Me trae esto:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría obtener algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo los siguientes Datos Por la sugerencia que me hace @Mauricio Arias Olave

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi tabla CAT_SEXO me dá el Tipo de SEXO y se Relaciona con CONDUCTORES mediante el Campo sexo_id que es un campo
de binarios si es 1=FEMENINO si es 0=MASCULINO la tabla CONDUCTORES se relaciona con la tabla TRAMITES
que unicamente me sirve para Relación con LICENCIAS de la cual obtengo la Fecha. y el conteo lo hago en base al campo
sexo_id de la Tabla CONDUCTORES.

Esos son los Datos de Mis tablas espero también eso explique el porque uso todas las tablas.
 La consulta que trae es correcta, pero lo que busco es que los datos del Campo Pertenecientes SEXO esten en Diferentes Campos @gbianchi, estuve probando con LIKE y similares pero no lo consigo, por eso recurro a esta zona de Master, creo que debe ser una comparación en base al Campo de SEXO_ID de mi tabla CAT_SEXO la cual es una tabla fija de allí tomo los datos.

Comment: Por favor [edit] la pregunta agregando ejemplos de qué contiene cada tabla que usas en la consulta. Por ejemplo: En el resultado esperado, ¿qué significan los resultados separados por sexo?. Agrega una descripción clara  de porqué haces esta consulta y qué resultados esperas obtener.

Comment: la tabla tramites y licencias sobran en ese query no? y como vas a agrupar los resultados finales? o siempre vas a devolver una sola fila?

Comment: @Mauricio Gracias ya Anexe Información. Espero me haya explicado.

Comment: @gbianchi Ahí explico el porque las uso, Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que la forma más directa es usando una suma condicional:

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)                                             as TOTALDIA
        COUNT(CASE WHEN co.sexo_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as SEXOFEMENINO,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN co.sexo_id = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as SEXOMASCULINO
        FROM CONDUCTORES AS co INNER JOIN TRAMITE AS tr 
        ON co.conductor_id = tr.conductor_id INER JOIN LICENCIAS AS lic 
        ON tr.licencia_id = lic.licencia_id INNER JOIN CAT_SEXO AS se 
        ON se.SEXO_ID = co.sexo_id      
        WHERE YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
        AND MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

La consulta ahora no está supeditada al sexo (quitamos el filtro en el `WHERE`), pero lo que se condiciona es la suma.

Comment: Saludos, Excelente funciona Perfectamente de una forma mas Sencilla. Gracias me servirá para futuras consultas que deseo realizar, en base al  mismo tema y con mas simplicidad.

Answer (score 4):

Una forma de resolver esto, aunque nada performante, seria hacer las 3 sumas por separado en un solo query.

Primero, obtengamos un query que cuente uno u otro tipo, ese seria algo asi:

```
CONSULTA A:
SELECT 
    COUNT(co.sexo_id)
FROM 
    CONDUCTORES co
    JOIN TRAMITE tr ON co.conductor_id=tr.conductor_id
    join LICENCIAS lic on tr.licencia_id=lic.licencia_id
    join CAT_SEXO se on se.SEXO_ID=co.sexo_id      
WHERE   
    YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())
    AND co.sexo_id = 0
```

Este query va a contar todos los masculinos. Si en el where cambiamos `co.sexo_id = 1`, va a contar los femeninos.

O sea, que ahi tenemos las dos cuentas.

Como sqlserver admite selects sin from, podrias probar hacer algo asi:

```
CONSULTA C:
Select (CONSULTA A) as masculino, (CONSULTA B) as femenino
```

la consulta B, seria igual a la A, pero buscando para el otro sexo.

Eso, nos va a devolver una tabla con dos columnas, una para masculino y otra para femenino. Ahora solo tenemos que obtener la suma tambien.. y para eso, envolvamos la consulta anterior en otra:

```
SELECT *, masculino+femenino as total
FROM (consulta C)
```

De esta forma, obtenes lo que queres.

Comment: Gracias no había revisado pero también puede ser buena..

Answer (score 1):

Esta puede ser una opción:

- Declaras 2 variables que almacenarán los resultados del conteo o suma para cada sexo.
- Haces la consulta que *(según explicas en tu pregunta)* funciona, pero le añades al `WHERE` la condición `co.sexo_id`.
- Haces un `SELECT` para traer los resultados como deseas.

Este seria el resultado de mi explicación:

```
-- Variables que guardarán la cantidad (SUM o COUNT) según el sexo.
DECLARE @cantidad_datos_femenino AS INT = 0;
DECLARE @cantidad_datos_masculino AS INT = 0;

-- Establecer la cantidad de datos en las variables.
-- Femenino:
SET @cantidad_datos_femenino = (SELECT COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTALDIA
                                FROM CONDUCTORES AS co INNER JOIN TRAMITE AS tr 
                                ON co.conductor_id = tr.conductor_id INER JOIN LICENCIAS AS lic 
                                ON tr.licencia_id = lic.licencia_id INNER JOIN CAT_SEXO AS se 
                                ON se.SEXO_ID = co.sexo_id      
                                WHERE YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                                AND MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                                AND co.sexo_id = 1 /* FEMENINO. */);

-- Masculino:
SET @cantidad_datos_masculino = (SELECT COUNT(co.sexo_id) as TOTALDIA
                                 FROM CONDUCTORES AS co INNER JOIN TRAMITE AS tr 
                                 ON co.conductor_id = tr.conductor_id INER JOIN LICENCIAS AS lic 
                                 ON tr.licencia_id = lic.licencia_id INNER JOIN CAT_SEXO AS se 
                                 ON se.SEXO_ID = co.sexo_id      
                                 WHERE YEAR(fecha_captura) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                                 AND MONTH(fecha_captura) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                                 AND co.sexo_id = 0 /* MASCULINO. */);

-- Esta es la consulta con los resultados esperados:
SELECT SUM(@cantidad_datos_femenino + @cantidad_datos_masculino) AS [TOTAL DIA],
       @cantidad_datos_femenino AS [SEXOFEMENINO],
       @cantidad_datos_masculino AS [SEXOMASCULINO]
```

Comment: Bro, Los datos me los regresa Nulos, le omito el Order by porque no los permite pero aún así.

Comment: @Abraham he modificado mi respuesta quitando el group by y el order by. ¿Puedes explicar a qué te refieres con `pero aún así`?, ¿has visto la respuesta del usuario gbianchi?

Comment: esa es la Respuesta Bro. Sos un Capo.... Solo hay que añadir un ")" después de 1 y 0 respectivamente y Listo.... Gracias ya quedó.. :)

Comment: @Abraham, fue un error mío *(coloqué mal el comentario)*. Ya lo corregí en la respuesta. Saludos.